# Change DatePicker DayCell color

Tags: java, json, javafx, calendar, gson

I want to change the color of a DatePicker DayCell according to values in a Json file. The Json file looks like this:

```
    {
  "2019-01-22": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 17:17:23",
    "positive": "first Entry",
    "negative": "test1",
    "sliderValue": 0
  },
  "2019-01-16": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 16:46:56",
    "positive": "second Entry",
    "negative": "test2",
    "sliderValue": 1
  },
  "2019-01-23": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 16:47:10",
    "positive": "third Entry",
    "negative": "test3",
    "sliderValue": 2
  },
  "2019-01-24": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 16:47:18",
    "positive": "fourth Entry",
    "negative": "test4",
    "sliderValue": 4
  },
  "2019-02-19": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 17:01:51",
    "positive": "fifth Entry",
    "negative": "test5",
    "sliderValue": 6
  },
  "2019-02-20": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 17:01:56",
    "positive": "sixth Entry",
    "negative": "test6",
    "sliderValue": 8
  },
  "2019-03-13": {
    "timestamp": "2019.01.22 17:02:04",
    "positive": "seventh",
    "negative": "test7",
    "sliderValue": 10
  }
}
```

I want to change the colors of the day cell after the sliderValue which is below the upper object what is named after the date. The sliderValue goes from 0-10 in a distance of 1. For the Value 0 the day cell should be red, for 5 yellow and for 10 green.
The Json file is also extended or changed more often because it is a diary application. 
I've already found a post where this is shown but I can't transfer it to my situation...
here the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542312/javafx-datepicker-color-single-cell)

I got the calendar from the DatePicker.
Here is the code:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(datePicker);
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
```

If you need more lines of code from my program, just write a comment. I will add them then. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What about the linked post could you not transfer over or did not understand? It seems like that would do it with some modifications to the `cellFactory` logic.

Comment: @Hypnic Jerk I don't understand how I can do this in conjunction with my JSON file.

I just started programming last time and didn't really find much on the internet which helps me.